# Sharepoint Search REST API people SourceID gives 0 results

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, people-search, office-365-developer, pnpjs

I implemented on my Sharepoint Online tenant **Custom People Search Webpart** using Sharepoint Search REST API (here to be precise pnp/js library).

To find only people related hits, I used `SourceId: b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31` in search body ([List of common SharePoint 2013 Result Source IDs - Corey Roth [MVP] (dotnetmafia.com)](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2013/01/04/list-of-common-sharepoint-2013-result-source-ids.aspx)).

From today 05/02/2023 7:00AM CET, this request started to give 0 results no matter what is *queryText*. Till this time (or somewhere between Friday 4PM to 7AM Monday), it was >14k results. I tested my app on my company tenant and on my private Visual Studio Subscription tenant. All attempts yields 0 results.

Was there any global change on this topic?

Is there any alternative to this way mentioning I need to refine hits?

Answer (score 1):

There is no global change in the SharePoint search REST APIs. This is an issue at Microsoft end and happening for all SharePoint tenants.

Microsoft knows about the issue and currently they are working on fixing it.

You can find the detailed information at M365 admin center --> Service health:

[image]

Direct link to incident: [Some users may be unable to utilize the Classic Search People vertical within SharePoint Online](https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/home?#/servicehealth/:/alerts/SP712697) - You need admin access to open this link.